# On validation, how to compare two Date/Time fields?

Tags: validation, validation-rule, datetime

I have two Date/Time fields that need to compare, **ON my validation Check-Out time must be greater than check-in time.**

How to compare them in the validation rule?

```
CheckIn_Time (Date/Time)
CheckOut_Time (Date/Time)
```

I have tried the below rule, it compares the only date not time

`DATEVALUE(CheckIn_Time__c) > DATEVALUE(CheckOut_Time__c)`

Comment: What have you tried that has not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple arithmetic operators work when comparing a `Date/Time` to a `Date/Time`.

You must do conversions or other operations to extract the parts you need if you want to compare `Date` to `Date/Time`.

---

This Validation Rule: `CheckOut_Time__c <=  CheckIn_Time__c`

Resulted in this:

[image]

and this:

[image]